# How to get urls of images in google drive folder?

Tags: google-drive-api

Lets say I have 200 images in a google drive folder, is there a way I can get a direct URL to each of them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If they are publically shared.

you can see the link in your drive against any file, right click and click "get link" or click on file and click on link icon.

this link can be accessed with sdk as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable using Google Scripts, here's a script that will list your files with URLs. This will go a few layers deep, as well as finding all the files in the parent folder of where you put this.

To use, create a new spreadsheet and add this script. listFilesInFolder is the function you'll want to run. Just pare down the code if it's giving you too much information.

*This does use deprecated code, but if you have a one-time use, then this is your ticket.

```
function getParentFolder() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var SSID=ss.getId();

  var fileInDrive = DriveApp.getFolderById(SSID);
  var folderinDrive = fileInDrive.getParents().next().getName();

  return folderinDrive;
}

function listFilesInFolder() {
  var parentFolder = getParentFolder();
  Logger.log("Parent: " + parentFolder);
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder(parentFolder);
  var parentFiles = folder.getFiles();
  var folders = folder.getFolders();

  var file;
  var allFolders;
  var subFileList;
  var data;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet;
  sheet.clear();

  sheet.appendRow(["Name", "Date Created", "URL", "Type", "Last Updated", "Parent Folder"]);

  // Every file in the folder containing this file.
  for (var i = 0; i < parentFiles.length; i++) {
    file = parentFiles[i];

    var parentName = "";
    try {
      var parentName = file.getParents()[0].getName();
    } catch(err) {}   

    data = [ 
      file.getName(),
      file.getDateCreated(),
      file.getUrl(),
      file.getFileType(),
      file.getLastUpdated(),
      parentFolder
    ];

    sheet.appendRow(data);
  } 
  // Every subfolder in the folder containing this file.
  for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
    allFolders = folders[i];
    var parentName = "";
    try {
      var parentName = allFolders.getParents()[0].getName();
    } catch(err) {}    
    data = [ 
      allFolders.getName(),
      allFolders.getDateCreated(),
      allFolders.getUrl(),
      "folder",
      allFolders.getLastUpdated(),
      parentName
    ];

    sheet.appendRow(data);
  }


  for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
    allFolders = folders[i];
    var subFiles = allFolders.getFiles();

    for (var j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
      subFileList = subFiles[j];
      try {
        data = [ 
          subFileList.getName(),
          subFileList.getDateCreated(),
          subFileList.getUrl(),
          subFileList.getFileType(),
          subFileList.getLastUpdated(),
          subFileList.getParents()[0].getName()
        ];

        sheet.appendRow(data);
      } catch(err) {

      }
    }
  }
};
```